# how to create sharepoint custom login page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication, asp.net

Im creating custom login page for sharepoint that will use Forms Based Authenitcation. I've read couple articles how to do it, but something is not clear to me.

What class should my Login.aspx (and other forms such as ResetPassword.asxp, UpdatePassword and etc) inherit from:

1.LayoutsPageBase
2.System.Web.UI.Page
3.FormsSignInPage
4.IdentityModelSignInPageBase
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is a default FBA login page already there in

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\Login.aspx

Could you use that as a template ?

Answer (score 0):

The login page must be inherited from the  Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages.FormsSignInPage class according to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/07/09/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx) guide.

Comment: I tried doing that, but when i inherit from FormsSignInPages, im having trouble with inherited events (AuthenticatedEventHandler, LoggingInEventHandler). What i did is, im actually inheriting from IdentityModelSignInPageBase just to avoid some of the logic on FormsSignInPages level. Im getting expected results, im just curious how other people are doing it

Answer (score 0):

It should be inherited from IdentityModelSignInPageBase. 
Refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.identitymodel.pages.identitymodelsigninpagebase.aspx